# image quality issue in flash

Tags: flash, photoshop

Hi I am using `Flash CS5` and `Photoshop CS3`. The issue I am facing is while exporting from photoshop (optimized for web and devices) as **png-24** , most of the images lose their quality inside flash. I have tried to make the publish settings for image quality 100. On lossless compression of the images, the image gets blurry. The total quality of display is highly degraded in flash in comparison to that of photoshop. Kindly guide if anyone else has faced the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes on imported images in Flash:

1. Scaling or rotating images will degrade its quality *significantly* unless you enable smoothing in the properties panel for the individual image.
2. Positioning lossless images without smoothing enabled to a *whole pixel* (that is, not 10.55, but 10) will give the best results. Non-whole pixel positioning will cause a slight blur (important for logos, text, etc), as will enabling smoothing.
3. Sometimes, lossless images will automatically be set to have JPEG compression (just check the settings each time you import).
4. Avoid scaling *up*.

[image]

But most importantly, import what you have as vector wherever possible.