# resizing images in Flash without losing image quality

Tags: flash, adobe

I am new to Flash and am, using the CS6 version. Unlike Illustrator and Photoshop, images in Flash lose quality even when you reduce the size of an image.

I have seen Flash animations that use vector logos, so I know its possible to expand and contract the size of images while maintaining the image sharpness.

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Not related to programming, doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: @Blubberguy22 This *could* be programming-related. user3754191: Have you taken a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867533/image-quality-issue-in-flash?rq=1 ?

Comment: Oh, my bad. Darn, I can't un-downvote it now, too late.

Comment: @Blubberguy22 If my recent edit gets accepted, you will be able to undownvote if you'd like.

Comment: @admdrew Alright; I originally thought this was just something related to software, which doesn't belong on SO

Comment: @Blubberguy22 I honestly agree with your original comment, but maybe OP is doing some CS6 scripting? Or something?

Comment: I tried to remedy the issue by importing vector images from illustrator but the image gets treated the same way. perhaps there is a specific way to configure the image when importing it to flash? if this is the case, I am searchIng for the answer to this question.